# Using 2D arrays to build a 3D array in for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, audio

I'm trying to define a function which:

1. Reads in each 1min audio file from a directory
2. Calculates features for each second of each 1min file, returning the numpy array `feats` of shape (60, 96, 64) for each file, where 60 denotes each second
3. Takes the mean across all seconds in a 1min file to return the array of `features_from_one_file` shape (96, 64)
4. Appends each of these mean arrays to the 3D array `features_allfiles`, so that each 1min file is represented as a dimension (correct term?) in `features_allfiles`. e.g if five 1min files were used, this would have shape (5, 96, 64)
5. I then aim to adapt this so that any files n minutes in length will have their `feats` arrays split by n, so that the average feats are returned on a per minute basis.

I've got stuck at step four, so could use help with this, any suggestions for step 5 also welcomed!

Here's my code so far:

```
def get_features(directory):
audio_fs = os.listdir(directory) #list of all files in directory

features_allfiles = np.empty([0,96,64])

for f in audio_fs:
    #find file:
    path = os.path.join(directory, f)
    
    #calculate features from audio file:
    feats = vggish_input.wavfile_to_examples(path)
    print(np.shape(feats))                    #this returns (62, 96, 64) for a 1min file
    
    #Get the mean of the these 62 2D arrays
    features_from_one_file = np.mean(feats, axis = 0) 
    print(np.shape(features_from_one_file))   #this returns (96, 64)
    
    #Append the mean of each file to features_allfiles, so that it has shape (n, 96, 62), where n = number of files
    ???
    
return features_allfiles
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.vstack` but first you have to add a new dimension to `features_from_one_file`:

---

### **EDIT**

```
As suggested @hpaulj, the best practice is to stack only once, so you need to collect all `features_from_one_file` in a list and then stack them:

import numpy as np

all_feats = []
for i in range(5):
    #create features    
    features_from_one_file = np.random.randn(96,64)
    #append Broadcasting first to have dimension 1x96x64
    all_feats.append(features_from_one_file[None,:] )

#stack all at once
features_allfiles = np.vstack(all_feats)

print(features_allfiles.shape)
```

wich outputs

```
(5, 96, 64)
```

---

Old propossal: stack by one (this is slower)

```
features_allfiles = np.empty([0,96,64])

for i in range(5):
    #new features
    features_from_one_file = np.random.randn(96,64)
    
    #vertical stack, [None,:] recast array adding new dimension first
    # you can also use features_from_one_file.reshape(1,96,64)
    features_allfiles = np.vstack([features_allfiles,
                                   features_from_one_file[None,:]])


print(features_allfiles.shape)
```

wich outputs

```
(5, 96, 64)
```

Comment: We usually recommend collecting the arrays in a list, and doing just one `vstack` at the end. (or `stack`)